# Moving channel fields to different group?

Tags: channel

I am using the Brilliant Retail e-commerce plugin and currently I have a Channel Group, "Bikes," with 8 channel fields associated with it. I would like to move all those channel fields to a different group, "[BrilliantRetail]," is this possible?

I know I can edit Channel Group assignments and tell the BrilliantRetail group to use the Bikes channel fields, but I already have some custom channel fields in the BrilliantRetail group as well so I would like to just merge the Bikes channel fields with the BrilliantRetail group.

**UPDATE** I edited the database and changed the channel fields group_id to the one corresponding to BrilliantRetail group and that worked. However, the channel field data did not transfer with it. Is there a way for me to re-associate the channel field data as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't hep you with the question in your update, but regarding your original question, I use MX Tool Box by Max Lazar when I need to move or duplicate fields. It allows you to clone fields and export/import fields from group to group.

You can work on just a single field, or a batch/group of fields at once, and it  detects and allows you to solve conflics during import.

http://www.eec.ms/forums/viewthread/22/

Huge time saver for these situations.